# PHP Multiple navigation highlights

Tags: php

I'm using this piece of code below to highlight the "active" menu item on my global navigation.

```
<?php
    $path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $page = basename($path);
    $page = basename($path, '.php');
?>

<ul id="nav">
    <li class="home"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li <?php if ($page == 'search') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>><a href="#">Search</a></li>
    <li <?php if ($page == 'help') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>><a href="help.php">Help</a></li>
</ul>
```

All works great but, on a couple of pages, I have a second sub menu (sidebar menu) within a global page.

I basically need to add a OR type statement into the php somehow, but I haven't a clue a how.

Example of what i mean:

```
    <li <?php if ($page == 'help') OR ($page == 'help-overview') OR ($page == 'help-cat-1') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>><a href="#">Search</a></li>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve that this way:

```
<li <?php echo ($page == 'help' || $page == 'help-overview' || $page == 'help-cat-1'  ?  'class="active"'  :  ''); ?>><a href="#">Search</a></li>
```

Or you could use the function `in_array()` which is even better in my opinion:

```
<li <?php echo ($page == in_array('help', 'help-overview', 'help-cat-1')  ?  'class="active"'  :  ''); ?>><a href="#">Search</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks, Neither or those seem to work but if i apply it like this everything is good! <li <?php if ($page == 'help' || $page == 'about-us' || $page == 'management-team') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>><a href="help.php">Help</a></li>. Thanks

Comment: @Blackbird: It could be fixed now as I have updated my answer. Also, as you see, in PHP you use `||` instead of `OR`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not exactly what you're asking but I would recommend you to use simple css :)

```
ul#nav a.active, ul#nav a:active {
   color: green;
   background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a convention to look for a base, or parent, page:

```
$page = explode("-", $page)[0];  # should return 'help' for all help pages

<li <?php if ($page == 'help') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>><a href="#">Search</a></li>
```

This means you'll need to use the convention `<parent_page>-<sub_page>` when naming pages.